# Node not rotating?

Tags: swift, rotation, scenekit

The node doesn't rotate when I run the app. No matter what I change rotation to, the node will remain as if it was at '0,0,0,0'.

```
class CustomSCNNode: SCNNode {



var positionToSlideFrom = SCNVector3Zero

convenience init(geometry: SCNGeometry, initialPosition: SCNVector3, rotation: Float) {
    self.init()
    self.geometry = geometry
    self.position = initialPosition
    self.positionToSlideFrom = initialPosition
    self.rotation.y = rotation


}

}
```

//node passed into GeometryNodes to be moved by user. This is where nothing happens!

```
class GeometryNodes {


let sphere = CustomSCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.05), initialPosition: SCNVector3(0,1.3,0), rotation: -45)

func addNodesTo(_ parentNode: SCNNode) {
    sphere.rotation.y = -45
    parentNode.addChildNode(sphere)

}

func slideFunction(_ node: CustomSCNNode, translation: Float) {
    //Can't add anything yet due to rotation not working

  }
func slideFunction2(_ node: SCNNode, translation: Float) {

    node.position.z =  translation
    //node.position.x =  translation

}

func slide(xTranslation: Float) {

    slideFunction(sphere, translation: xTranslation)
}
func slide2(zTranslation: Float) {
    //let gameScene = BallScene()
    slideFunction2(sphere, translation: zTranslation)

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply rotation by 45 deg around Y axis, you need to specify the rotation as:

```
self.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, 45 * M_PI / 180.0)
```

Similarly ensure you express the XYZ axis correctly if you are rotating around X or Z axis.

Alternatively, you can also use [`eulerAngles`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1407980-eulerangles) property to specify rotation as such:

```
self.euelerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, 45 * M_PI / 180.0, 0)
```